# Richtextbox.Insert function changes my strings color in box

Tags: c#

I am new in this site:) and have a problem about color of RichTextBox.

Now I created a colored RichTextBox and for example I colored my strings in the RichTextBox.
Like that;

"String1" red colored.
"String2" blue colored.
These strings are entered in to the text box via keyboard and I have a color selection tool which defines the color of entered strings.
But when I trying to add a string via c# code with RichTextBox.Insert function all of these strings color changes to Green.
Note: The RichTextBox Fore Color property is set to Green.
Help me!!

Comment: please show your code or better show a minimal working example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I can not put code here because the project is a secret project. I am sorry for this.:(

Comment: then the solution and our hints are also secret. btw what is secret about posting a simple application with a textbox, your color chooser and a button that adds the text and changes the text to green? Does not sound very secret.